# Binary Search with multiple midpoints confusion

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I'm reviewing for my midterm and this specific question is causing me some issues.

This is the following array to perform the binary search:

---

[image]

---

the value I want to search for is 150.

To start off, I take the first element which is 0, and the last element which is 15.

---

(start + end) / 2,

(0 + 15) / 2 = 7

The value at the array of 7 is 90.

90 < 150, so the value is contained in the right side of the array.

---

The array now looks like this:

[image]

---

Continuing with the same logic

(start + end) / 2

(8 + 15) / 2 = 11.

However, according to the professor I should be at the value 12 here. I'm not sure what i am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please add brackets: `start + end / 2` is not the same thing as `(start + end) / 2`

Comment: I think you'll have to take this to your professor.  The given code does, indeed, return a middle value to the low side (when the array is of even length).  Either way will work for bisecting the list, provided you've properly handled the transition from 2 elements to 1.

Comment: your professor is considering the ceil of the mid point i.e. `15/2 = 7.5 = 8` which in the next iteration become `(9 + 15) /2 = 12`. Both are alright

Answer (score 0):

The algorithms were written even before the computers were invented.
Computers are simply a tool or a device which implements the algorithm in an efficient manner which is why it is fast.

The binary search which you are performing here is relevant to computers as the array are indexed from 0 (counting usually starts from 0 in computers), that is why you are getting 11 which is correct in point of computers.

But for the humans counting starts from 1 and the so the result according to professor is 12. 
While writing algorithms we write in according to the perception of the human and we twist it a little to implement in our machine.